# Plotting predicted values causes error: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pytorch

How do I properly write the code to plot the predicted values in this linear regression model?

I am using this tutorial to learn Linear regression:https://www.deeplearningwizard.com/deep_learning/practical_pytorch/pytorch_linear_regression/

I was able to successfully implement GPU. My issue is plotting the predicted values. I tried searching for solutions to learn how to keep the values as a tensor, but it seems that I don't have the syntactical knowledge to do this.

Here is where I'll start

```
epochs = 100
for epoch in range(epochs):
    epoch += 1

    # Convert numpy array to torch Variable
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        inputs = (torch.from_numpy(x_train).cuda())
        labels = (torch.from_numpy(y_train).cuda())
    else:
        inputs = (torch.from_numpy(x_train))
        labels = (torch.from_numpy(y_train))

    # Clear gradients w.r.t. parameters
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # Forward to get output
    outputs = model(inputs)

    # Calculate Loss
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

    # Getting gradients w.r.t. parameters
    loss.backward()

    # Updating parameters
    optimizer.step()

    # Logging
    print('epoch {}, loss {}'.format(epoch, loss.item()))
```

Prediction is made here and I choose to use cuda

```
predicted = model(Variable(torch.from_numpy(x_train).requires_grad_().cuda()))

print("Predicted")
print(predicted)
print("Output")
print(y_train)

plt.clf()

# Get predictions

#predicted = model(Variable(torch.from_numpy(x_train).requires_grad_().cuda()))

# Plot true data
plt.plot(x_train, y_train, 'go', label='True data', alpha=0.5)
```

The error is called here after it is unable to plot

```
# Plot predictions
plt.plot(x_train, predicted, '--', label='Predictions', alpha=0.5)

# Legend and plot
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Error Given:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Test with GPU/Linear regression.py", line 101, in <module>
    plt.plot(x_train, predicted, '--', label='Predictions', alpha=0.5)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2795, in plot
    is not None else {}), **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1666, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 225, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 391, in _plot_args
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 271, in _xy_from_xy
    if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.plot` function expects its inputs to be `numpy` arrays, rather than `torch.tensor`.
You can use [`.numpy()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.numpy) to view the internal data of the tensor as a `numpy` array.

Try

```py
with torch.no_grad():
  plt.plot(x_train, predicted.cpu().numpy(), '--', label='Predictions', alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: I tried putting this in, but it only told me: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'cpu' Then I took off cpu and it told me: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'numpy' Finally I took off everything except for the with statement and I got the same error of:'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Comment: @AdrienDridri please see my edit. I think I understand your problem: your x is numpy array while y is a tensor.

Comment: It worked thak you so much! Learned a lot from this!

Answer (score 2):

Ndim is a property required by matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
torch.Tensor.ndim = property(lambda x: len(x.size()))
N = 42
t = torch.rand(N)
plt.plot(t)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

But PyTorch doesn't have that for tensor till version 1.2 I think.

This part `torch.Tensor.ndim = property(lambda x: len(x.size()))` you can add and you can plot PyTorch tensors without problems.

[image]

Comment: I feel that I'm closer, and thank you for this information it helped me understand something new. I have this error now: TypeError: can't convert CUDA tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.